# Getting 500 error with Flask Application on RaspberryPi

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I've build a small webpage that grabs an RFID ID from a reader and checks if the user already exists and if so redirects them to a specific page. On my laptop everything is working fine, but since I've moved it over to the RPi I'm getting a weird 500 error.

What the terminal messages should look like:

```
starting
{'MemberID': u'7A0092B6F9A7'}
Member ID 7A0092B6F9A7
{"MemberExists":true,"MemberName":"WORK","State":"Logged In"}
True
Noooooo
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 10:52:00] "POST /index HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Sending confirmation for check in
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 10:52:00] "GET /getSignIn HTTP/1.1" 200 -
It worked
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 10:52:00] "GET /activity HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What it actually looks like:

```
starting
{'MemberID': u'7A0092B6F9A7'}
Member ID 7A0092B6F9A7
{"MemberExists":true,"MemberName":"WORK","State":"Logged Out"}
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 16:02:12] "POST /index HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1504, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1264, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1262, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/flask/app.py", line 1248, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/pi/connectedLogin/app/views.py", line 64, in index
    isMember = q.json()["MemberExists"]
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
Sending confirmation for check in
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 16:02:12] "GET /getSignIn HTTP/1.1" 200 -
It worked
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Aug/2015 16:02:12] "GET /signup HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Here's my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(): 
    global checkCheck
    global userIdentifier
    print "starting"
    location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'} 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        global userIdentifier
        global isMember
        global memberID
        checkCheck = True
        member = {'MemberID': request.form['cardID']}
        memberID = request.form['cardID']
        print member
        print "Member ID " + memberID
        q = requests.post("https://external_DB/login.json", data=member)
        print q.text
        isMember = q.json()["MemberExists"]
        print isMember
        userIdentifier = q.json()["MemberName"]

        if isMember == False:
            #do stuff for a new member
            print "YEAH"
            print userIdentifier

        else:
            #do stuff for a recurring member
            print "Noooooo"

        return render_template('index.html',
                    location = location,
                    user = member
                    )
```

And my html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ location['mspace'] }} - Makerspace </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='bubbler.jpeg')}}" style="width:100%"></img>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center; display: table; width: 100%; height: 77%">
            <h1 style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle">Welcome to {{ location['mspace'] }} - Place your card on the reader to begin</h1>
        </div>
    </body>  
    <script>
    function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
               var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
               xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
               xmlHttp.send(null);
               return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }

    var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){checkFunc()}, 1000);

    function checkFunc(){
        var json = httpGet("/getSignIn");
            console.log("yes!");
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            console.log("new checkin = "+obj.newCheckin);
            console.log("MemberID = "+obj.MemberID);
            console.log("IsMember? "+obj.isMember);
            if(obj.newCheckin){
                clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
                checkUser(obj.isMember, obj.memberID);
            }
    }
    function checkUser(isMember, memberID){
        if(isMember == false){
            window.location = "signup";
        }
        else{
            window.location = "activity";
        }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an older version of `requests`. Until version 1.0.0, the `response.json` attribute is a *property* returning the JSON object directly. If you are using a Linux distribution based on Debian or Ubuntu then you probably have version 0.8.4 installed.

Either upgrade the `requests` library to a newer version (your version is nearly 3 years out of date), or remove the `()` call:

```
isMember = q.json["MemberExists"]
userIdentifier = q.json["MemberName"]
```

Comment: That's really weird (I only insalled it last week) - could that be an issue with RPi specifically? Is there an easy RPi terminal command to update the `requests` library ?

Comment: @Mike: it is not specific to RPi, other than that your RPi distribution is based on Debian or Ubuntu. Use a virtualenv and install requests and Flask into that instead of relying on system-supplied packages.

Comment: I'm running a virtualenv and tried installing requests again but I get the following: `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /use/lib/python2.7/dist-pakages` but I can't seem to get the upgrade to work

Comment: @Mike: your virtualenv version is older too and doesn't ignore `site-packages` (or in this case `dist-packages`) by default. Re-create it with `virtualenv --no-site-packages`. Then make sure you use the `pip` command from the virtualenv, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the core of the error message:

```
  File "/home/pi/connectedLogin/app/views.py", line 64, in index
    isMember = q.json()["MemberExists"]
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

That means the value of `q.json` is a 'dict' object.  That line of code expects it to be a method that can be called.

I am unfamiliar with flask, but familiar with python.  Either q.json needs to be redefined as a method, or that line of code needs to be changed so it doesn't call it.  Eg `isMember = q.json["MemberExists"]`

Comment: It is not Flask, but the `requests` library.

Comment: Yeah that totally worked - not sure why I didn't get thrown that error with my local machine